# Nginx sets HTTP_HOST to punycode

Tags: nginx, php, idn

I have a unicode domain name. [It is configured as punycode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764750/unicode-domain-name-in-nginx-server-name) in the `server_name` directive.

When I call `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in my PHP code, I get that same punycode version. How do I configure Nginx to set `HTTP_HOST` to the unicode value instead?

As a hotfix, I call `idn_to_utf8($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46)` at the top of my script. But I would like this to be done automatically outside of my website code.

Closest I found is [IDN and HTTP_HOST](https://serverfault.com/questions/112035/idn-and-http-host) but it's 10 years old and for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any support for different character sets in the FastCGI interface, that is used between nginx and PHP.

Therefore even if nginx was able to decode the domain name into UTF-8, there wouldn't be a way to for it to send it properly to PHP.

Your best bet is to add the decoding of `HTTP_HOST` header into your front controller.